# How should I show editable data after it has been submitted with a form so that I can reuse a form components?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, web, user-experience

If I was making a website where the user submits some data using a form and then the user is redirected to a page with a unique URL where they can view this data, what is the best way to display this data to user in a way in which they can make updates to it?

To give some context I am using react and right now I am showing the same form again on the view data page, but as the forms have slightly different display options, such as some fields being disabled and some extra buttons I am repeating the same form in two seperate components which seems to go against the react way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would personally do it is have all your form elements in a single component and use it for the create and edit page, then just pass a "isCreating" or "isEditing" prop, or something similar. In that component, you can then conditionally disable your inputs.

**Component**

```
const SomeForm = ({ isEditing }) => {
  const onSubmit = () => {
    if (isEditing) {
      // Make request to update endpoint
    } else {
      // Make request to create endpoint
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input disabled={isEditing} />
        <input />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Create Page Usage**

```
<MyForm />
```

**Edit Page Usage**

```
<MyForm isEditing />
```

Note that if you're doing a ton of conditional logic/rendering based on whether you're creating or editing a form, it might be better to split it into two separate form components. If you're simply disabling some inputs on the edit page and doing different submit logic, then I think this is fine.